# loop through and load a zipped folder of yaml files

Tags: python, yaml, unzip, zip, pyyaml

I have a zipped folder containing 15 000 yaml files. I'd like to iterate through  the folder using yaml.safe_load so that each file is in a dictionary format and I can extract information from each file that I need. I've written some code so far using zipfile.ZipFile and yaml.safe_load but it only works for the first file in the zipped folder. Would anyone please mind taking a look and explaining what I'm misunderstanding please?

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile("D:/export.zip")
files = zip_file.namelist()
print(files)
for i in range(10):
    with zip_file.open(files[i]) as yamlfile:
        yamlreader = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
        print(yamlreader["identifier"])
```

for now I'm just iterating through 10 files to make life easier. Eventually I'd like to do the whole 15 000. "identifier" is a key in the yaml file.

This is the error:

```
10.5281/zenodo.1014773
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/estho/PycharmProjects/GSOC3/testing_dataextraction.py", line 20, in <module>
    yamlreader = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\constructor.py", line 41, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "C:\Users\estho\PycharmProjects\GSOC3\lib\site-packages\yaml\scanner.py", line 260, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "yamlfile_10_5281_zenodo_1745362.yaml", line 4, column 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like in the file `"yamlfile_10_5281_zenodo_1745362.yaml"` there is a bad token name. Try running it without this file. In python `\t` is representative of a tab and so cannot be included in a string ect normally without escaping it.

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking at the files in more detail and they are formatted differently - extra tabs inserted. I'll go back and try and sort that out in the file creation.